# Gamepad API - Different browser axis mapping

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, gamepad-api

I'm using Gamepad API and, in the same computer, with chrome and firefox, I get different axis mapping, axis numbering and button mapping.
Is there any way to make them use the same mapping?
Or some library?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

User agents are free, according to the [spec](https://w3c.github.io/gamepad/#remapping), to remap buttons if a known configuration is detected. They do not have to, though. You can manually check the mapping and remap in your client-side code, though.

> Each device manufacturer creates many different products and each has
> unique styles and layouts of buttons and axes. It is intended that the
> user agent support as many of these as possible.
>
> Additionally there are de facto standard layouts that have been made
> popular by game consoles. When the user agent recognizes the attached
> device, it is RECOMMENDED that it be remapped to a canonical ordering
> when possible. Devices that are not recognized should still be exposed
> in their raw form.